# From ELements Loaded or not?

Tags: javascript

Hi I make randomly calling multiple ajax calls.how i can check all ajax calls are completed and values get loaded in combox and multiple boxes,PLease give any solution other than ajax status,Any javascript event which triggers when all elements loaded???,I tried prototype document.observe("dom:loaded", function()  but its not working for ajax calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how i can check all ajax calls are completed and values get loaded in combox and multiple boxes,PLease give any solution other than ajax status

Why?  What's wrong with using the AJAX request status, which is the canonical way to determine the status of the request (and thus success or failure)?

There might be a legitimate reason for this restriction (though at first glance it appears not), but if so then it's because you're doing something unusual, such as making requests that you expect to "fail".  If this is the case, then you'd need to make clear exactly what the constraints are anyway.

Failing that, just check the status and ensure that the remote server is returning the right status for requests (if it's under your control).